# Needs to show the list of items in label with based on the format coming from response

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an api call response where i will get the list of items as two format.

```
"items" : [
      {
        "menu_code" : "NDS",
        "name" : "Monday"
      },
      {
        "menu_code" : "NDN",
        "name" : "Tuesday"
      }
    ]
```

format 2 is here :

```
"items" : [
      {
        "unit" : "Nos",
        "name" : "Chapathi\/Pulkas",
        "quantity" : 2
      },
      {
        "unit" : "Cup",
        "name" : "Palya\/Curry",
        "quantity" : 1
      }
    ]
```

Now i have one label in my collection view. So based the response in my label i needs to show like below example :

`name - quantity unit ,
 name - quantity unit,
name - quantity unit ...etc` based on the count coming from response.

Another format :

```
name - menu_code, 
name - menu_code, 
name - menu_code ..etc
```

based on the count coming from response.

My model class :

```
struct Item : Codable {

    let unit : String?
    let name : String?
    let quantity : Int?
    let menuCode : String?

}
```

my collection view :

```
var names:[String] = []
    var qty:[Int] = []
    var unit:[String] = []
    var menuCode:[String] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionCell

  cell.productName.text = self.allCategory[indexPath.item].menuName
  let itemsData = self.allCategory[indexPath.row].items

    print(itemsData)

    for dt in itemsData {
       // print(dt)
        let nam = dt.name
        let unt = dt.unit
        let mCode = dt.menuCode
        let qtys = dt.quantity

        names.append(nam ?? "")
        unit.append(unt ?? "" )
        qty.append(qtys ?? 0)
        menuCode.append(mCode ?? "" )
       // cell.ProductsubLabel.text = itemsData


    }
return cell
}
```

So i have created an array but not sure how to append to label.And also i am not aware to difference the two format and to show in the label.Any help on this.

Thanks in advance !

Update :

third new format :

```
"items" : [
          {
            "unit" : "Nos",
            "product_name" : "Chapathi\/Pulkas",
            "quantity" : 2
          },
          {
            "unit" : "Cup",
            "product_name" : "Palya\/Curry",
            "quantity" : 1
          }
        ]
```

Comment: This cannot work. And never convert an array of distinct objects to multiple arrays. Don't do that. Please clarify what is going to be displayed in one cell. You got an array of categories (`allCategory`) which represents the data source array and each category has multiple `items`.

Comment: see i have one label in my collection view or textview, In that i need to append like here  `Chapathi\/Pulkas - 2 Nos , Palya\/Curry - 1 cup` like that with commas. if another format means like this `Monday - NDS, Tuesday - NDN` like that with commas in my label or textview

Comment: @vadian how can i achive that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite efficient solution is to add a `description` property in the struct which returns the appropriate data. If `unit` does not exist return the `menuCode` information otherwise `quantity` and `unit`

```
struct Item : Codable {

    let unit : String?
    let name : String?
    let productName : String?
    let quantity : Int?
    let menuCode : String?

    var description : String {
        let name = self.name ?? self.productName ?? "n/a"
        if unit == nil {
            return "\(name) - \(menuCode!)"
        } else {
            return "\(name) - \(quantity!) \(unit!)"
        }
    }
}
```

In `cellForItemAt` map the `items` to their descriptions and join the array by comma.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionCell

    let category = self.allCategory[indexPath.item]
    cell.productName.text = category.menuName

    let itemsData = category.items
    let subData = itemsData.map {$0.description}.joined(separator: ", ")
    cell.ProductsubLabel.text = subData

    print(subData)
    return cell
}
```

And delete the four ugly arrays above `cellForItemAt`

Comment: `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"name\", intValue: nil) (\"name\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Thanks for ur solution. Previously i tried little bit like ur solution that time also i got some same error..so only i left i was doing something wrongly. Now after update the solution also getting same

Comment: If you get an error, there are still more different `items`. Are there? In your example **all** items have a `name` key. Please add all possible differences

Comment: yes, u r right..i checked the response data...sorry for the inconvenience...they din inform me about this like they have added new format..i have updated my post

Comment: What a mess, please blame the owner of the service to send more consistent data! I will update the answer.

Comment: any help on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434614/how-to-save-struct-values-with-codable-decodable